# Using pure JavaScript, given a collection of objects and a filter object, return objects in collection with same key/value pair as the filter object

Tags: javascript, function, object, collections, filter

I have a pseudo-code for solving a certain problem in JavaScript but I can't seem to wrap my head on how to translate it to code:

```
var sampleCollection = [
  { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 },
  { 'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6 }
];

var sampleFilter = { 'a': 4, 'c': 6 };

function getCollectionFilter(collection,filter) {
    function collectionFilter(collection,filter) {
    //return if for each element in filter,
    //collection's key/value pair is same with filter's key/value pair
  }

  return collection.filter(collectionFilter);
}

getCollectionFilter(sampleCollection,sampleFilter);
// -> { 'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6};
```

I think lodash has the _.matches to solve this, but I would like to know why things are done in certain ways and what are the implications/consequences if done otherwise.

Bonus for giving context in the real world on why a solution/practice is "best"

Comment: Why would that filter also return back `'b': 5`?

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel because the `a` and `c` values match?

Comment: Oh, ok, I misunderstood how the filter worked.

Comment: Briefest is : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38664372/747579

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)** methods

```js
var sampleCollection = [{
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
}, {
  'a': 4,
  'b': 5,
  'c': 6
}];

var sampleFilter = {
  'a': 4,
  'c': 6
};

function getCollectionFilter(collection, filter) {
  // filter out elements and return
  return collection.filter(function(v) {
    // get all object keys 
    return Object.keys(filter)
      // use `every` method and check all values are equal
      .every(function(k) {
        // compare values
        return filter[k] == v[k];
      });
  })
}
console.log(
  getCollectionFilter(sampleCollection, sampleFilter)
);
```

---

With [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you can make it one line.

```js
var sampleCollection = [{
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
}, {
  'a': 4,
  'b': 5,
  'c': 6
}];

var sampleFilter = {
  'a': 4,
  'c': 6
};

function getCollectionFilter(collection, filter) {
  return collection.filter(v => Object.keys(filter).every(k => filter[k] == v[k]))
}
console.log(
  getCollectionFilter(sampleCollection, sampleFilter)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Pranav C Balan's answer (beat me to the punch)... I'm just using a filter-factory for creating functions to pass to `Array.prototype.filter` rather than requiring the collection as a parameter and doing a pre-loop check for the existence of matching keys prior to actually comparing values.

```
let filterer = test => {
  let keys = Object.keys(test).sort();
  let keyMatch = new RegExp(keys.toString);
  return obj => {
    let objKeys = Object.keys(obj).sort().toString();
    return objKeys.match(keyMatch) && keys.every(k => test[k] === obj[k]);
  }
};

let passes = arrOfObjects.filter(filterer(testCase));
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional answer. Pranav's answer was a concise edit to my code to make it work. I noticed that you're using ES6 features. How does that compare in terms of performance, scalability, and readability (style adoption) compared to the one above? I don't have production experience so I'm curious about real-world practices rather than isolated algorithm challenges I've been exposed to so far.

Comment: @John it depends on whether the ES6 is native or transpiled. I can tell you that the source code tends to be (in my experience from porting projects to ES 6) about 25~30% shorter overall. In terms of real-world practices, AFAIK ES 6/Babel or Typescript (which uses the same core-js transpiler as babel) are pretty standard. In terms of perf, I haven't profiled it but unless its in a hot loop it shouldn't matter even with an order of magnitude difference.